# Angular lazy load modules in code (no routing)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, devextreme, angular10, devextreme-angular

In aspnet core app I currently have this in `app.modules.ts`

```
import {
  DxDataGridModule,
  DxButtonModule,
  DxNumberBoxModule,
  DxTextBoxModule,
  DxSelectBoxModule,
  DxValidatorModule,
  DxValidationGroupModule,
  DxValidationSummaryModule,
  DxTextAreaModule,
  DxLoadPanelModule,
  DxTemplateModule
} from 'devextreme-angular';
```

my home page uses only 2 of the above. I want to delay loading of the rest up to the moment user navigates to the pages they are used on.

lets say I have `home.component`, `page1.component`, `page2.component`

home uses 2 DX modules and page1 and page2 use various subsets of all of them..

I spent a lot of time honestly trying to comprehend how lazy loading works but failed. read few dozens of blogs - all show how to either load a single component in `RouterModule` or a single module.

Can I not use `RouterModule` at all and just load the modules in `onInit` of `home.component`? if not - how do I load bunch of modules with await?

RouterModule now is:

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'page1', component: Page1Component }, 
{ path: 'page2' , component: Page2Component },
```

Comment: I don't know if is your case, but if you are looking for lazy loading non routes modules this link https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093 could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import the 3rd party modules inside the sub modules, they will only load if the sub module gets loaded. Remove them from your global `app.module.ts`.

So your main module could look like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: "page1",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./module1/module1.module").then(m => m.Module1Module)
      },
      {
        path: "page2",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./module2/module2.module").then(m => m.Module2Module)
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And your first sub module using only the `DxTextBoxModule` for example:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DxTextBoxModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: "",
        component: Page1Component
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [Page1Component]
})
export class Module1Module {}
```

Your second sub module using only the `DxSelectBoxModule` for example:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DxSelectBoxModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: "",
        component: Page2Component
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [Page2Component]
})
export class Module2Module {}
```

Here is a working sample: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/devextreme-example)

Answer (score 0):

For this particular issue, Angular introduced the lazy-loading concept.

What you need to do here is, each component that you mentioned above, home, page-1 and page-2 each component should be made into a module and then you can use the lazy-loading.

The file structure should be something like this:

```
home
|__home.component.html
 __home.component.scss
 ___home.component.spec.ts
 ___home.component.ts
 ___ home.module.ts


// This particular home.module.ts will have homeComponent as declarations and its necessary imports and exports. 

// This will be the same for page-1 and page-2 as well. 

// Now in your routing.module, it will be like this: 

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'page-1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./page1/page1.module').then(m => m.Page1Module)
  }
];


this will load that part only when the route is inititated
```

Comment: I saw these things already. i just dont understand it.. what I am asking specifically is not how to lazy load **my** modules/components but the 3rd party I use (UI elements with DX prefix). they dont have routes.